# TFS build Error Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found, while file exists. Sometimes build is success

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I am using TFS 2013 to build my project but sometimes I am getting the error as:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found.Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I have gone through many answers and found a lot of workaround to fix it but **“in my case the problem is that sometime my build is success and sometimes it is failing.”**

Let say I am running my build for 10 times then 3-4 times it is passing and 6-7 times it is giving error.

I have checked the path on server and the file

> "C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"

exists at the same location where TFS build is looking for.

I have also visited the link

[TFS build errors a file not found, while file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256047/tfs-build-errors-a-file-not-found-while-file-exists)

but there is no answer provided on this thread.

I want to do very minimal changes. Please suggest what would be the possible solution to make .targets file always available.

**Update:**

I have found a similar question at the link

[TFS Build missing .targets files intermittently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638484/tfs-build-missing-targets-files-intermittently)

but the answer provided at this thread does not solve my problem and even if it's a kind of question again not the solution that's why I have started a separate thread.

Comment: If you use MSBuild command to build the project manually on your build agent machine, will you reproduce this issue?

Comment: Do you install VS 2013 on your build agent server?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, yes I have installed VS 2013 on build agent machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Build missing .targets files intermittently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638484/tfs-build-missing-targets-files-intermittently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the items below:

1. Clean the Cache folder on your build agent machine. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`.
2. Clean the cache folder on your TFS machine: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data`
3. Try to use the NuGet package [MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/12.0.4), referencing them in your project.
4. Try to create another light project to test whether you would get the same issue.